# How to make a string longer than 1 word in discord.py?

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord.py bot that 'reccomends' your server to other members. When you type "!buy [price you want to pay] [short advertisement]", an invite link to your server will appear. Although, when I try to make the short advertisement longer than one word, it only shows 1 word, the first word.

Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def buy(ctx, price: int, advertisement):

    buyer = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 0)

    if buyer not in amounts:
        author = ctx.message.author

        noacc = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        noacc.set_author(name=f'You do not have an account.', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png')
        noacc.add_field(name='Type ":register" to make an account.', value='\u200b', inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=noacc)
    elif amounts[buyer] < price:
        author = ctx.message.author

        notaff = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        notaff.set_author(name=f'You cannot afford this transaction.', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png')
        notaff.add_field(name='Join some more servers, then try again!', value='\u200b', inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=notaff)
    elif price < 5:
        author = ctx.message.author

        larger = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        larger.set_author(name=f'Amount must be 5 or larger.', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png')
        larger.add_field(name='Sorry!', value='\u200b', inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=larger)

    else:

        author = ctx.message.author

        buy = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.blue()
        )

        buy.set_author(name=f'Purchased {price} Members.', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/723566996817575948/723932425369026560/comrade.png')
        buy.add_field(name='This is what people will see when they type ":find"', value='\u200b', inline=False)
        buy.add_field(name=f"**{ctx.guild}**", value=link, inline=False)
        buy.add_field(name=f'{advertisement}', value='\u200b', inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=buy)

        amounts[buyer] -= price
```

If you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord.py separates the arguments by space. So you have 2 possible solutions

1. Surround you advertisement with `""` when running the command in Discord.
   OR
2. Change your argument types as follows:

```py
@client.command()
async def buy(ctx, price: int, *args):
    advertisement = ' '.join(args)
```

And keep the rest of the code unchanged. This will capture all the words from your command and join them in a single string making out your advertisement.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join them all into a single argument by doing:

```
@client.command()
async def buy(ctx, price: int, *, args):
    ctx.send(args)
```